# removing Case sensitivity and substring check in php

Tags: php

I want to find out whether the input string is a substring of another string or not , is there any function that do so ignoring case sensitivity? The substring check should be done ignoring case sensitivity.
Please tell me about any such function

Comment: [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Comment: but is it case insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)**

> Returns the matched substring. If needle is not found, returns FALSE.

```
if(stristr("Hello","hello world")!==FALSE)
{
  // Yes needle is a part of haystack
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

*Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a* string

```
if(stripos("This is a test string","A Test")!==FALSE)
{
    echo "Yes";
}
```

---

Check this note for [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) from manual:

> **Note**: If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs
>   within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function
>   strpos() instead.